# Generified implementation of Visitor pattern in Java

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I've made some research trying to develop a type conversion framework which provides an ability to convert instances of a source class (e.g., Foo) to instances of result classes (e.g., Bar or Baz). The framework should provide an ability to use different conversion logic (i.e., different converters) for the same pair of a source and result. It also should be extendable, i.e. allow of adding new converters for new and existing pairs of a source and result. One more requirement is typesafety, i.e. any attempt to convert an instance of some source class to an instance of a result class without converter implementing appropriate conversion logic should lead to compile time error.

I decided to use a [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) with converters as Visitors and convertable classes as Elements. To provide extendability and typesafety I decided to use generics. So the first implementation of the conversion framework I made being influenced by some article in the Internet (unfortunately I've lost the link) was...

**Conversion framework with statefull converters**

Here are the core interfaces of the framework, Converter and Convertable:

```
    public interface Converter<V extends Converter<V,A>, A extends Convertable<V,A>> {

        void convert(A convertable);
    }


    public interface Convertable<V extends Converter<V,A>, A extends Convertable<V,A>> {

        void convertWith(V converter);
    }
```

Generics make an implementation of `Convertable` accept only implementations of `Converter` which can convert them and make an implementation of `Converter` visit only implementations of `Convertable` which it's made to convert. Here is an example of such converters:

```
interface FooConverter extends Converter<FooConverter,Foo> {

    void convert(Foo convertable);

    void convert(FooChild1 convertable);

    void convert(FooChild2 convertable);
}


public class Foo2BarConverter implements FooConverter {

    private Bar result;

    public Bar getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void convert(Foo convertable) {
        this.result = new Bar("This bar's converted from an instance of Foo");
    }

    @Override
    public void convert(FooChild1 convertable) {
        this.result = new Bar("This bar's converted from an instance of FooChild1");
    }

    @Override
    public void convert(FooChild2 convertable) {
        this.result = new Bar("This bar's converted from an instance of FooChild2");
    }
}


public class Foo2BazConverter implements FooConverter {

    private Baz result;

    public Baz getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void convert(Foo convertable) {
        this.result = new Baz("This baz's converted from an instance of Foo");
    }

    @Override
    public void convert(FooChild1 convertable) {
        this.result = new Baz("This baz's converted from an instance of FooChild1");
    }

    @Override
    public void convert(FooChild2 convertable) {
        this.result = new Baz("This baz's converted from an instance of FooChild2");
    }
}
```

And here are some classes which could be converted with that converters:

```
public class Foo implements Convertable<FooConverter, Foo> {

    @Override
    public void convertWith(FooConverter converter) {
        converter.convert(this);
    }
}


public class FooChild1 extends Foo {

    @Override
    public void convertWith(FooConverter converter) {
        converter.convert(this);
    }
}


public class FooChild2 extends Foo {

    @Override
    public void convertWith(FooConverter converter) {
        converter.convert(this);
    }
}
```

Here are result classes, i.e. `Bar` and `Baz`:

```
public class Bar {

    private String message;

    public Bar(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}


public class Baz {

    private String message;

    public Baz(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

And here is a code which tests that converters:

```
Foo fooObj = new Foo();
Foo fooChild1Obj = new FooChild1();
Foo fooChild2Obj = new FooChild2();

// converting to bar
Foo2BarConverter foo2BarConverter = new Foo2BarConverter();

fooObj.convertWith(foo2BarConverter);
System.out.println(foo2BarConverter.getResult().getMessage());

fooChild1Obj.convertWith(foo2BarConverter);
System.out.println(foo2BarConverter.getResult().getMessage());

fooChild2Obj.convertWith(foo2BarConverter);
System.out.println(foo2BarConverter.getResult().getMessage());

// converting to baz
System.out.println();
Foo2BazConverter foo2BazConverter = new Foo2BazConverter();

fooObj.convertWith(foo2BazConverter);
System.out.println(foo2BazConverter.getResult().getMessage());

fooChild1Obj.convertWith(foo2BazConverter);
System.out.println(foo2BazConverter.getResult().getMessage());

fooChild2Obj.convertWith(foo2BazConverter);
System.out.println(foo2BazConverter.getResult().getMessage());
```

and output built by this code

```
This bar's converted from an instance of Foo
This bar's converted from an instance of FooChild1
This bar's converted from an instance of FooChild2

This baz's converted from an instance of Foo
This baz's converted from an instance of FooChild1
This baz's converted from an instance of FooChild2
```

Take a look at `result` field in `Foo2BarConverter` and `Foo2BazConverter`. That's the main drawback of the implementation. It makes converters statefull which is not always handy. Trying to avoid this drawback I developed...

**Conversion framework without double dispatching**

The main point of this implementation is to parametrize converters with result classes and return results from `convert` method of `Converter` and `convertWith` method of `Convertable`. Here is how it looks in code:

```
public interface Converter<A extends Convertable<A>,R> {

    R convert(A convertable);
}

public interface Convertable<A extends Convertable<A>> {

    <R> R convertWith(Converter<A,R> converter);
}

public interface FooConverter<R> extends Converter<Foo,R> {

    @Override
    R convert(Foo convertable);

    R convert(FooChild1 convertable);

    R convert(FooChild2 convertable);
}

public class Foo2BarConverter implements FooConverter<Bar> {

    @Override
    public Bar convert(Foo convertable) {
        return new Bar("This bar's converted from an instance of Foo");
    }

    @Override
    public Bar convert(FooChild1 convertable) {
        return new Bar("This bar's converted from an instance of FooChild1");
    }

    @Override
    public Bar convert(FooChild2 convertable) {
        return new Bar("This bar's converted from an instance of FooChild2");
    }
}

public class Foo2BazConverter implements FooConverter<Baz> {

    @Override
    public Baz convert(Foo convertable) {
        return new Baz("This baz's converted from an instance of Foo");
    }

    @Override
    public Baz convert(FooChild1 convertable) {
        return new Baz("This baz's converted from an instance of FooChild1");
    }

    @Override
    public Baz convert(FooChild2 convertable) {
        return new Baz("This baz's converted from an instance of FooChild2");
    }
}

public class Foo implements Convertable<Foo> {

    @Override
    public <R> R convertWith(Converter<Foo,R> converter) {
        return converter.convert(this);
    }
}

public class FooChild1 extends Foo {

    @Override
    public <R> R convertWith(Converter<Foo,R> converter) {
        return converter.convert(this);
    }
}

public class FooChild2 extends Foo {

    @Override
    public <R> R convertWith(Converter<Foo,R> converter) {
        return converter.convert(this);
    }
}
```

`V` is removed from `Convertable` declaration because having a result class in `Converter` declaration would have us in fact to parametrize implementations of `Convertable` with result classes. It would bound each implementation of convertable to the only result class it could be converted to. So `convertWith` in `Convertable` refers received converters with `Converter<A,R>` interface. And that's the problem. Now implementations of `Convertable` invoking received converter will allways invoke `convert` which is defined in `Converter` interface and not `convert` methods which override it in `Converter` implementations. In other words `convert(FooChild1 convertable)` and `convert(FooChild2 convertable)` in `Foo2BarConverter` and `Foo2BazConverter` will never be called. Basically, it kills the main notion of Visitor pattern, double dispatching. Here is a test code...

```
Foo fooObj = new Foo();
Foo fooChild1Obj = new FooChild1();
Foo fooChild2Obj = new FooChild2();

// converting to bar
Foo2BarConverter foo2BarConverter = new Foo2BarConverter();
System.out.println(fooObj.convertWith(foo2BarConverter).getMessage());
System.out.println(fooChild1Obj.convertWith(foo2BarConverter).getMessage());
System.out.println(fooChild2Obj.convertWith(foo2BarConverter).getMessage());

System.out.println();

// converting to baz
Foo2BazConverter foo2BazConverter = new Foo2BazConverter();
System.out.println(fooObj.convertWith(foo2BazConverter).getMessage());
System.out.println(fooChild1Obj.convertWith(foo2BazConverter).getMessage());
System.out.println(fooChild2Obj.convertWith(foo2BazConverter).getMessage());
```

and its output which demonstrates that overriding methods aren't called in this implementation.

```
This bar's converted from an instance of Foo
This bar's converted from an instance of Foo
This bar's converted from an instance of Foo

This baz's converted from an instance of Foo
This baz's converted from an instance of Foo
This baz's converted from an instance of Foo
```

Next implementation I tried to make stateless converters with was...

**Converters with parametrized methods**

The main notion here is to parametrize only methods which I want to return a conversion result without parametrizing declarations of interfaces.

```
public interface Converter<V extends Converter<V,A>, A extends Convertable<V,A>> {

    <R> R convert(A convertable);
}

public interface Convertable<V extends Converter<V,A>, A extends Convertable<V,A>> {

    <R> R convertWith(V converter);
}

interface FooConverter extends Converter<FooConverter,Foo> {

    <R> R convert(Foo convertable);

    <R> R convert(FooChild1 convertable);

    <R> R convert(FooChild2 convertable);
}

public class Foo2BarConverter implements FooConverter {

    @Override
    public Bar convert(Foo convertable) {
        return new Bar("This bar's converted from an instance of Foo");
    }

    @Override
    public Bar convert(FooChild1 convertable) {
        return new Bar("This bar's converted from an instance of FooChild1");
    }

    @Override
    public Bar convert(FooChild2 convertable) {
        return new Bar("This bar's converted from an instance of FooChild2");
    }
}

public class Foo2BazConverter implements FooConverter {

    @Override
    public Baz convert(Foo convertable) {
        return new Baz("This baz's converted from an instance of Foo");
    }

    @Override
    public Baz convert(FooChild1 convertable) {
        return new Baz("This baz's converted from an instance of FooChild1");
    }

    @Override
    public Baz convert(FooChild2 convertable) {
        return new Baz("This baz's converted from an instance of FooChild2");
    }
}

public class Foo implements Convertable<FooConverter, Foo> {

    @Override
    public <R> R convertWith(FooConverter converter) {
        return converter.convert(this);
    }
}

public class FooChild1 extends Foo {

    @Override
    public <R> R convertWith(FooConverter converter) {
        return converter.convert(this);
    }
}

public class FooChild2 extends Foo {

    @Override
    public <R> R convertWith(FooConverter converter) {
        return converter.convert(this);
    }
}
```

Testing code

```
Foo fooObj = new Foo();
Foo fooChild1Obj = new FooChild1();
Foo fooChild2Obj = new FooChild2();

// converting to bar
Foo2BarConverter foo2BarConverter = new Foo2BarConverter();
System.out.println(fooObj.<Bar>convertWith(foo2BarConverter).getMessage());
System.out.println(fooChild1Obj.<Bar>convertWith(foo2BarConverter).getMessage());
System.out.println(fooChild2Obj.<Bar>convertWith(foo2BarConverter).getMessage());

System.out.println();

// converting to baz
Foo2BazConverter foo2BazConverter = new Foo2BazConverter();
System.out.println(fooObj.<Baz>convertWith(foo2BazConverter).getMessage());
System.out.println(fooChild1Obj.<Baz>convertWith(foo2BazConverter).getMessage());
System.out.println(fooChild2Obj.<Baz>convertWith(foo2BazConverter).getMessage());
```

and it's output

```
This bar's converted from an instance of Foo
This bar's converted from an instance of FooChild1
This bar's converted from an instance of FooChild2

This baz's converted from an instance of Foo
This baz's converted from an instance of FooChild1
This baz's converted from an instance of FooChild2
```

At first glance looks great. But in fact this solution isn't typesafe. For example the following call

```
fooObj.<Baz>convertWith(foo2BarConverter).getMessage()
```

wouldn't cause a compile time error. But it would lead to ClassCastException in runtime.

So the general question is the following.

**Is there a way to make a stateless generifyed typesafe Visitor with Java?**

**UPD:** I've added links to sources of all three implementations: [1st](http://www.filedropper.com/statefullcovnerterstar), [2nd](http://www.filedropper.com/nodoubledispatchingtar) and [3rd](http://www.filedropper.com/parametrizedmethodstar)

Answer (score 1):

Your converters are simply functions, you probably do not need a "framework" to compose them. And your third try do not make much sense:

```
<R> R convertWith(V converter);
```

mean: "given something (the V converter that know nothing about the R you want), give me anything (arbitrary R)". As you found out this does not work.

Simple Implementation using the [corrected visitor pattern](http://logji.blogspot.ch/2012/02/correcting-visitor-pattern.html):

```
interface FooConverter<R> extends Function<Foo, R> {

  R convert(Foo convertable);

  R convert(FooChild1 convertable);

  R convert(FooChild2 convertable);

  default R apply(Foo foo) { return foo.convertWith(this); }
}

public class Foo2BarConverter implements FooConverter<Bar> {

  @Override
  public Bar convert(Foo convertable) {
    return new Bar("This bar's converted from an instance of Foo");
  }

  @Override
  public Bar convert(FooChild1 convertable) {
    return new Bar("This bar's converted from an instance of FooChild1");
  }

  @Override
  public Bar convert(FooChild2 convertable) {
    return new Bar("This bar's converted from an instance of FooChild2");
  }
}

public class Foo2BazConverter implements FooConverter<Baz> {

  @Override
  public Baz convert(Foo convertable) {
    return new Baz("This baz's converted from an instance of Foo");
  }

  @Override
  public Baz convert(FooChild1 convertable) {
    return new Baz("This baz's converted from an instance of FooChild1");
  }

  @Override
  public Baz convert(FooChild2 convertable) {
    return new Baz("This baz's converted from an instance of FooChild2");
  }
}

public class Foo{

  public <R> R convertWith(FooConverter<R> converter) {
    return converter.convert(this);
  }
}

public class FooChild1 extends Foo {

  @Override
  public <R> R convertWith(FooConverter<R>  converter) {
    return converter.convert(this);
  }
}

public class FooChild2 extends Foo {

  @Override
  public <R> R convertWith(FooConverter<R> converter) {
    return converter.convert(this);
  }
}

public void test() {
  Foo fooObj = new Foo();
  Foo fooChild1Obj = new FooChild1();
  Foo fooChild2Obj = new FooChild2();

  // converting to bar
  Foo2BarConverter foo2BarConverter = new Foo2BarConverter();
  System.out.println(fooObj.convertWith(foo2BarConverter).getMessage());
  System.out.println(fooChild1Obj.convertWith(foo2BarConverter).getMessage());
  System.out.println(fooChild2Obj.convertWith(foo2BarConverter).getMessage());

  System.out.println();

  // converting to baz
  Foo2BazConverter foo2BazConverter = new Foo2BazConverter();
  System.out.println(fooObj.convertWith(foo2BazConverter).getMessage());
  System.out.println(fooChild1Obj.convertWith(foo2BazConverter).getMessage());
  System.out.println(fooChild2Obj.convertWith(foo2BazConverter).getMessage());

  // does not compile:
  fooObj.<Baz>convertWith(foo2BarConverter).getMessage();
}
```

Then if you want some more framework, you may want to look into lenses: https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/tree/master/core/src/main/java/fj/data/optic

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thought about such solution. Besides that Converter and Convertable are needed for some reasons I deliberately omitted in my post (it's too big even without that) these interfaces form a basis of the framework. Without them there will be separate converters connected with nothing to each other.

Comment: Converter are basically Function, and you can compose functions. Added that to my response.

Answer (score 0):

You could just ditch Visitor Pattern as there is a better solution for Java.

## The pitfall of Visitor Pattern:

### It is intrusive, and anti-pattern

The visitor pattern use double-dispatch, that usually goes like this:

```
public class ParentDataModel
{
    public void accept(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class ChildDataModel extends ParentDataModel
{
    // no need to implement accept() by the child itself
}

public class Visitor
{
    public void visit(ParentDataModel model)
    {
        // do something with it
    }

    public void visit(ChildDataModel model)
    {
        // do something with it
    }
}
```

Why on earth a data model need to be aware of visitor? A data model should only hold the data relevant to the model.

### Does not go well with existing objects from external frameworks

What if you need to do something with, say Number, Double, that are from the JDK.

Even say you're willing to make a wrapper around each object you need in your project, it's hell tedious, and think about how many classes you will have to refactor to get this to work.

```
public class NumberWrapper
{
    private Number value;

    public void accept(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.visit(value);
    }
}

public class DoubleWrapper
{
    private Double value;

    public void accept(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.visit(value);
    }
}

public class Visitor
{
    public void visit(Number value)
    {
        // do something with it
    }

    public void visit(Double value)
    {
        // do something with it
    }
}
```

## Solution: One class rules them all

```
public static class SuperConsumer implements Consumer
{
    private Map<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> consumers = new HashMap<>();
    private Consumer<?> unknown = o -> System.err.println("Unknown object type");

    public SuperConsumer()
    {
        consumers.put(Number.class, o -> consumeNumber(o));
        consumers.put(Double.class, o -> consumeDouble(o));
    }

    private void consumeNumber(Number value)
    {
         System.out.printf("Consuming: %s\n", value.getClass().getName());
    }

    private void consumeDouble(Double value)
    {
         System.out.printf("Consuming: %s\n", value.getClass().getName());
    }

    private Consumer findConsumer(Object object)
    {
        Consumer consumer = consumers.get(object.getClass());

        Class superClazz = object.getClass().getSuperclass();
        while (consumer == null && superClazz != Object.class)
        {
            consumer = consumers.get(superClazz);
            superClazz = superClazz.getSuperclass();
        }

        Class<?>[] interfaces = object.getClass().getInterfaces();
        for (int i = 0; consumer == null && i < interfaces.length; i++)
        {
            consumer = consumers.get(interfaces[i]);
        }

        return consumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Object object)
    {
        Consumer consumer = findConsumer(object);
        if (consumer == null)
        {
            consumer = unknown;
        }
        consumer.accept(object);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Consumer consumer = new SuperConsumer();
        Arrays.asList(new Double(1.0), new Integer(1), new Float(1.0f)).forEach(o -> consumer.accept(o));
    }
}
```

Comment: Will a compile time error occure if a consumer is called with an object of a type unsupported by the consumer? One of advantages given by the visitor pattern is type safety.

Comment: No, there won't be compile time error, if you look closely, the consumer takes an `Object`. For unsupported type, you just provide a fallback consumer, or even throwing an exception, which strategy to go with depends on the use case.